# How to enforce an MNDA?

Tags: intellectual-property

If you believe the company you signed an MNDA with is violating the terms by ripping off your IP, what is your first course of action?  How about your second and third?  Can someone knowledgeable in IP infringement describe the general steps.

Comment: First step is talk to a lawyer.

Comment: While I presume from context that you are discussing some for a non-disclosure agreement (NDA), it is best practice to spell out every acronym in a question at least once for the benefit of readers not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's always going to be a fact-specific situation, but the first step is to conduct whatever factual investigation is feasible to disprove your belief.

If your investigation indicates that your belief is correct, you send a cease and desist letter. If that doesn't work, you proceed to litigation.